# Your display name's pronunciation is already reserved by another Action - but I deleted it days ago

Tags: actions-on-google

I started to develop an action a while ago. Learnt a few things, decided to delete and start again. Now I am getting:

> "Could not reserve your pronunciation '(name)' because: Your display
>   name's pronunciation is already reserved by another Action. If you
>   need further guidance, please contact support"

I deleted the original action about a week ago, [contacted support](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/?prio=medium) 4 days ago but no reply. I really need to use that name to match the Alexa skill version. Is there a "trash" area it is hiding out in, or some kind of "force destroy project" action I need to complete to recycle the name?

Also, is it the case that, unlike Alexa, no two actions can have the same invocation? So it is possible that in the few minutes between me deleting the other apps and generating the new one, that someone sneaked in and stole my name? And way of getting more diagnostic data? It does not appear in the assistant directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a Google Cloud Project, it will be fully deleted [after thirty days](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects). If you want to reclaim the name, you should be able to go to the original project and rename it to something else. If your name is trademarked, you should be able to request an exception.

Actions are all part of a global namespace, so two cannot have the same name. But if you don't see it in the directory, then it definitely didn't launch.

Comment: Thank you - in fact, Google finally replied within 90 minutes of your reply. They said "Recover the old project using the link in the email sent.
Change the old project's invocation name
This should free up the desired invocation and you should be able to use it on your new project."
However, I have been through all my projects on all accounts, checked everything. Still cannot do it. Is there any way of finding which account the invocation is associated with?

Comment: If an action that you do not own isn't published, there's no method for you to find the owner.

Comment: When it says "Your display name's pronunciation is already reserved by another Action", is it possible that this might also apply to a project or a dialogflow of the same name? Or is it possible that something needs to be "built" again with a throwaway name to free up the proper name? But then, actions aren't "built", they save instantly, right?
I just seem to be spending days trying to figure this out, really keen to get to the bottom of this. Thanks!

Comment: It would only be with respect to the Actions on Google namespace.